# Expressions for someone who likes doing things alone and doesn't like help

Tags: expressions, epithet-requests

What expressions are there for someone who likes to be alone and independent?
"Lone runner" is what comes to my mind, but I don't think I've really heard it, to be honest. Could anyone help?

Comment: A "sone" is a unit of loudness.

Comment: *loner* or *lone wolf*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Maverick' or 'lone wolf' are the words you are looking for I believe.

> Maverick: an unorthodox or independent-minded person.
>
> Lone wolf: a person who prefers to act or be alone.

Comment: That's it, tks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not 'lone runner', but 'lone ranger' fits the definition.

Answer (score 1):

*Recluse* - a person who lives a solitary life and tends to avoid other people.

"He lives a *reclusive* life in a small island in Bahamas.

*loner*,  *lone wolf*, *solitary*  have similar meanings.